# Question regarding definitionof compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactification

> **Definition:** A *compactification* of a topological space $X$ is an ordered pair $\left(Y,h\right)$, where
> $$(1)\quad Y\text{ if a compact } T_2\text{-space}$$
> $$(2)\quad h\colon X\to Y\text{ is an embedding}$$
> $$(3)\quad h[X]\text{ is dense in } Y;\text{ }\overline{h[X]}=Y.$$

My question is, does $X\subseteq Y$ need to be true? I ask this because the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a compactification of $(0,1)$, though, its's simply not true that $(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{S}^1$....

Comment: $h:(0,1)\to S^1$, $h(x) = (\cos(2\pi x), \sin(2\pi x))$ is an embedding

Comment: @RyanK: Thanks, but doesn't really answer the question, i.e. does it need not be that $X\subseteq Y$?

Comment: Ahh sorry, $h[X]\subseteq Y$ but not necessarily $X\subseteq Y$ as this example illustrates.

Comment: @RyanK: I figured, just wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: the definition doesn't specify that $X$ needs to be a subset of $Y$. But, $h(X)$ is s subset of $Y$, and $h(X)$ is homeomorphic to $X$, so a copy of $X$, namely $h(X)$ is indeed a subset of $Y$.

Comment: @Mirko: So $X\cong_\text{hom.}h[X]\subseteq Y$, does this mean topologically $X$ and $Y$ are the same?

Comment: It means that $X$ and $h(X)$ are topologically the same. (Not $X$ and $Y$, unless $X$ is already compact, in which case $h(X)=Y$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but $Y$ does contain a “topological copy” of $X$, to wit $h[X]$, which is homeomorphic to $X$ (by the definition of an embedding). It’s technically convenient not to have $X \subseteq Y$, it allows for more flexible ways to construct compacifications. And the $h$ is the way $X$ sits in $Y$, as it were. The notion of equivalent compactifications uses the embedding. It’s to make the notion “categorical”, if you know categories.

Comment: Thanks! I have little knowledge of categories, but are you saying the morphisms would be the embedding maps?

Comment: @D.Math In the sense that a map between compactifcations of $X$ has to respect the two embeddings too, in a commutative diagram. So it also involves "arrows" not just objects.